# Recreating history without loop or cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a case when i want to create a destination log table based on snapshot data in source without using loops(WHILE or CURSORS).

Scenario:

1. In the first run, i want to populate my destination table from the data in source table like in image below:

   [image: Screenshot of expected results after 1st run]
2. In the next run, I would like that the existing Jhon record remains as-is and new Jhon record is inserted and marked as Active=N. And finaly, new Terry record is inserted. Basically, insert as inactive which is missing on source since last time and also insert new records in general.

   [image: Screenshot of expected results after 1st run]

Any thoughts how to achieve this without loops?

Comment: Please don't post images of data, even when they are simple datasets like this, it puts the effort of translating your samples on the folks you're asking for help.
From your sample data, I don't understand the basis for the 'Jhon 5.10.2021' row: there is nothing in the sample or the question to indicate why that row should exist for Jhon.

Comment: Look at exists or joins for this, groupid, name and date not existing in the destination table for adding, but before updating the active status of the ones present.

Comment: @paneerakbari, row for Jhon(5.10.2021) should exist to log in dest table that as of date he is no longer active and Terry replaced him.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Providing DDL saves us from making assumptions, e.g. `Date` is `NVarChar(MAX)`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless performance a big concern, wouldn't necessarily recommend using storing active flag as it can get out of sync. I'd probably use a view like so

### Calculated Active Flag in View

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
WITH CTE_RowNum AS (
    SELECT RowID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY ID DESC)
        ,ID,GroupID,[Name],[Date]
    FROM DestinationTable
)
SELECT ID,GroupID,[Name],[Date],Active = CASE WHEN RowID = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM CTE_RowNum
```

But if you need to store active flag, just update the old rows to inactive when you insert

### Update Active Flag with Insert

```
/*Be sure to include both in 1 transaction so if insert fails, update is rolled back as well*/
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE D
SET Active = 'N'
FROM DestinationTable AS D
INNER JOIN SourceTable AS S
    ON D.[Name] = S.[Name]

/*Then insert source table into destination table*/

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Hi @Stephan thanks for helping. The biggest challenge would be in 2nd run when i have Terry instead of Jhon in my source snapshot table. That should be reflected in my destination table by entering Jhon as a new record first with a date which would represent its end date and next it needs to add Terry as a new person with its date when he started.

Comment: @haskiero_1 What if Terry replaced two people, or Mark is also missing from the 2nd run of source, or two people in source replaced three people in destination? The danger of oversimplifying the problem to the single case where exactly one person conveniently replaced exactly one other person, and only explaining with pictures...

Comment: @haskiero_1 ... in other words ... what ties Terry directly to Jhon, and for that matter, how do you know that's even the same Mark?

Comment: @AaronBertrand..i was maybe wrong when i stated that Terry is replacing Jhon. The importance is at inserting an new "inactive" record to dest table for the very first time when one person stops coming from source table for the same GroupID.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Terry and Jhon are just under same GroupID, nothing else ties them

Comment: @haskiero_1 And what about when you have a second Mark join the group? Or the date is different in "Source table," wherever that comes from?

Comment: @haskiero_1 Then how do you know Jhon became inactive _on the same day_ as Terry became active? Does `05.10.2021` represent the day the script ran or is it somehow tied to the date in `SourceTable`?

Comment: `like you suggest Jhon should be marked active on the same day when Terry joined(become active), not the sysdate since the snapshot of the data represents that as-of 2022-01-06 Terry becomes active and on that same date, Jhon becomes inactive.` SQL Server doesn't know those two dates are tied together, only you do. As I said above, it doesn't make sense to retroactively update the history because if source table contains two new people (let's say `Sally, Jan 12` and `Kevin, Jan 13`) and one or two or seven people left, what date would you put on the people who left? Stop focusing on 1-for-1.